# Tweepy Python suddenly becoming very slow, ProxyError

Tags: python, tweepy

I've been using Tweepy for crawling tweets in certain area with geocode as parameter since 2 month ago. Everything was fine until last week, Tweepy suddenly becoming very slow and terminate itself.

Error message :

```
tweepy.error.TweepError:Failed to send request: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.twitter.com',port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /1.1/search/tweet.json?count=200&geocode=-6.1750%2C106.8283%2C438.37km&since=2016-04-21&until=2016-04-22 (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', error(10054,'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host')))
```

I've already set the proxy (as usual) using:

```
set http_proxy=http://152.118.24.10:8080
set https_proxy=https://152.118.24.10:8080
```

Anyone have same problem or know the solution?

Comment: did you reach the limit?

Comment: i already use try catch. if reach the limit, sleep for 5 minutes, and it works fine before